# How to set the "noDataTemplate" text for KendoUI Autocomplete in Angular when no data matches

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

The Kendo documentation for jQuery includes the feature to set the text for the autocomplete box when no data is found

- [kendo documentation for jQuery](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/nodatatemplate)

but I can't make it work in Angular and can't find the right documentation. Need help to figure out which property to use. I have tried a couple of variations as follows:

```html
    <kendo-autocomplete #contactslist [data]="contacts" class="contacts" valueField="label"
      [kendoDropDownFilter]="{operator: 'contains'}" [filterable]="true" placeholder="To: Email Adress*"
      (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" noDataText="blah">
    </kendo-autocomplete>
```

```html
    <kendo-autocomplete #contactslist [data]="contacts" class="contacts" valueField="label"
      [kendoDropDownFilter]="{operator: 'contains'}" [filterable]="true" placeholder="To: Email Adress*"
      (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" [noDataText]="blah">
    </kendo-autocomplete>
```

```html
    <kendo-autocomplete #contactslist [data]="contacts" class="contacts" valueField="label"
      [kendoDropDownFilter]="{operator: 'contains'}" [filterable]="true" placeholder="To: Email Adress*"
      (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" [noData]="blank">
    </kendo-autocomplete>
```

and also with `[noDataTemplate]="blank"`

The output I keep getting is:
[image]

- [kendo for angular documentation for changing the label](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/CustomMessagesComponent/#toc-nodatatext)

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: ['.k-i-warning { font-size: 2.5em; } h4 { font-size: 1em;}'],
    template: `
      <kendo-autocomplete [data]="listItems">
          <ng-template kendoAutoCompleteNoDataTemplate>
              <h4><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"></span><br /><br /> No data here</h4>
          </ng-template>
      </kendo-autocomplete>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public listItems: Array<{ text: string, value: number }> = [];
}
```